# Npgsql data type mapping of Character from Postgresql to .NET Core 2.0

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, mapping, npgsql

In a PostgreSQL database I have a RFC column which is sort of a code to identify Enterprises and people in Mexico (for taxes purposes), code that I need to store in my database. The format of this 'code' it's like the next one:

AAAXXXXXXAXX -> where A's are letters and X's are numbers.

I want to store RFC column as primary key. As far as I've searched, Postgres Character data type is good for this, and I have the SQL query of it as pgAdmin4 generates:

```
rfc character(13) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_empresas PRIMARY KEY (rfc)
```

But, inside Visual Studio using Package Manager Console and the next command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Host=localhost;Database=database;Username=pgadmin;Password=xxxx" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -force
```

It generates my models that are mapped as the tables in my database.
The question here is, **how can I work correctly if .NET *char* datatype only holds a single character and the property RFC is generated as follows?**

```
public char Rfc { get; set; }
```

This first approach stores only the first character. I can see it in pgAdmin4

[Database record saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngpZk.png)

I've tried to change Rfc property data type(as I know that some .NET data types can match to others in PostgreSQL as we can see in the next link [Npgsql Supported Types](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html) ) as string like this:

```
public string Rfc { get; set; }
```

But this Table is also related to another 4 or 5 Tables in my Database, and I get too many errors when I try to change the data type of this property in my model (as it is also related in models).

I have to say that I have tried this but it throws an exception.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries.
```

**Edit 1:**
I'm using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL version 2.0.1

Comment: Can you please update with the version of EF Core you're using? To be sure I understand, are you saying that EF Core scaffolds a column of type `character(13)` as a .NET `char` instead of a `string`? If so, can you please open an issue on https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL?

Comment: @ShayRojansky you couldn't describe it better. Yes, EF Core scaffolds that column as a .NET `char`property. I was sure it was supposed to scaffold it as `string` instead of `char`. I'll open that issue right away. Any thoughts about how could I manage this?

Comment: In the meanwhile, you can try with a `varchar` column instead of a `char` - there's isn't that big a difference between them (see [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html)).. And finally, scaffolding is just a one-time process - you're free to edit the scaffolded source and change char to string, it should work.

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/370

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed for version 2.0.2 of the Npgsql EF Core provider which will be released very soon.

See https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/370 for the github issue.